# Expressing vectors as a unit vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I  just started vectors and was solving some problems. One of them says

> A car is moving at the speed $10\,\mathrm{m/s}$. Write the velocity vector of the car in unit vector notation if the car is moving towards North East.

The problem seems fairly easy.
I solved it like this:

$$ \hat a={\cos\left(\frac\pi4\ \right)\hat\imath+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\ \right) \hat\jmath }$$

This gives
$$ \hat a= \frac {\hat\imath+\hat\jmath}{\sqrt2}$$

Then upon multiplying by the magnitude we get the vector $$10 \frac {(\hat\imath+\hat\jmath)} {\sqrt2}\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$$
But, according to the book it is $$5 \frac{\hat\imath+\hat\jmath} {2}\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$$ which are clearly not equal. It should've been $5\sqrt2 (\hat\imath+ \hat\jmath)$. Did I falter somewhere?

Comment: Looks like your book is wrong.

Comment: I think the same too. I don't see a problem in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily check which one is correct by calculating the norm explicitly. Because $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are orthonormal, the norm of a general vector
$$ \vec{V} = A\hat{i} + B\hat{j}$$
is
$$ |\vec{V}| = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2} $$
which is really just the Pythagorean theorem.

Doing this for the book answer we get
$$ |\hat{a}_\mathrm{book}| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{12.5} \neq 10$$

Your answer on the other hand is
$$ |\hat{a}| = \sqrt{50 + 50} = \sqrt{100} = 10 \quad ✔$$
so it looks like the book is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You  cleared all my confusion at once.